# Trying to display latest Tweet

Tags: javascript, twitter

I've been using a few tutorials to help me display my latest tweet, but I haven't had any success since it suddenly stopped working about a week ago.

This is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1"></script>
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="twitter_div"><ul id="twitter_update_list"><li>&nbsp;</li></ul></div>
```

But it comes up empty in JS fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/BVDVH/149/

I have no idea why, but it was working before and just stopped working on my website about a week ago.

### EDIT:

Answer in comments. Was not seeing last tweet because it was a re-tweet. Had to set it to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the script that handles the data loaded from twitter. The twitter API expects a callback of twitterCallback.

EDIT: didnt realize that blogger.js provided the callback. Answer fiddle is in the comments

Comment: Hmm... I added that in below my other JS, but still no luck.

Comment: Works fine for me... billclinton is a protected account, swap it with your own

Comment: Nope, I've been trying it with my own account. Can you get it to work in JSFiddle?

Comment: Maybe this will help with the situation. If I change `twitterCallback2&count=1"` to `twitterCallback2&count=5"` I get a single tweet, but not my last one. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Aha... I think I figured it out. Out of my last 5 posts. The very last one is a tweet while the first four are Re-tweets. Any idea on how to show retweets aswell?

Comment: Got it working. Had to add in the ability to show RT. Here is the JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/BVDVH/151/

Comment: Right, for some reason I overlooked the blogger.js. I haven't used blogger.js before, so wasn't familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

firstly this was answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863252/how-can-i-get-tweets-using-jquery)

however that example requires a plugin

a cleaner method is described [here](http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Using-jQuery-To-Get-Your-Tweets.aspx)

Comment: Don't want to use JQuery. Thanks for your input though.